# UIWebView with links

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink

I am creating a webview and loading content using "loadHTMLString" The content is loading I just can't get the links to work ex linking to google.com. Any help would be great.

```
UIWebView* newWeb = [[UIWebView alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(notificationPopUp.frame.origin.x+ 20,notificationPopUp.frame.origin.y-100,100, 100)]; 
//newWeb.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
newWeb.alpha = 0.7;
newWeb.opaque= NO;
newWeb.delegate= self;
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><title></title><style type=\"text/css\">a{text-decoration:none}</style></head><body><FONT COLOR=\"#484848\"><p>Hello this is a <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Test</a></p></FONT></body></html>"];  
[newWeb loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]; 
newWeb.userInteractionEnabled= TRUE;
[notificationPopUp addSubview:newWeb];
```

Comment: Are the links pointing to resources stored in your application bundle?

Comment: Information about a) what you expect the links to do and b) your observations of what it's currently doing would help.

Comment: In the example Im just trying to go to google. Mainly I just want to link to web sites.

Comment: Instead of posting code that works, can you post code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: The code posted doesn't work. I been "trying" to link to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to an empty project and links are clickable. The only thing I can think of is your notificationPopUp view is somehow preventing taps from going to the webview.

Comment: thanks for narrowing it down, ill find a work around for the popup then

Comment: yea, I was adding the webview to the button, probably wasn't receiving any touches. Changed it to where it adds it to the mainview.